# How to change the tab color based on a cell in the worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very large spreadsheet with lots of worksheets that I use to create invoices based on a project number. Each project doesn't get billed on a monthly basis. I have to print each invoice to PDF and to avoid having to open every tab to see if there is information to bill, I'd like to change the tab color based a cell which contains the total of the invoice.

I have used VBA very little but have found several macros that are trying to do the same thing but because they rely on something different, I can't get what I need. I found one that just turns all the tabs a color. I found one that changes the color based on a true/false formula. I don't have the knowledge around this code to change it so that if cell H22 is >0, it turns the tab a color.

The invoices created before I took my role aren't consistent so not all totals will be in cell H22 -- it could be H14. I'm even willing to put a button on each tab that I could press to apply the macro as I do my preliminary work on each tab. I just don't have the knowledge good enough to know how to write the code. Thanks!

Comment: If the cell that contains the total is inconsistent, then how would a macro know which cell to go after for the test? Does it say, in the cell to the left "Total:" or something? Does this logic get applied to every sheet in the workbook, or just sheets with a specific name?

Comment: Start with the macro recorder. Change tab colors, select some cells, and see what it gives you. Play around with it and update if you have more specific questions!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to find an cell that none of the worksheets use (say AZ99) and do the equivalent of the H22>0 example you described on each sheet.

e.g sheet1 might have AZ99 as X10>0, sheet2 might be Y11>0 or whatever.

Use the true/false VBA code to look at cell AZ99 or whatever the cell you choose is.